# Можно ли преобразовать строку в списк в Python?

Tags: python, reactjs

допустим есть переменная

`a = ['1, 2, 3, 4']`

и я должен получить все цифры из строки (1, 2, 3, 4) и поместить их в список
вот так

`b = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

вот запрос с реакт

```
        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('author', 1);
        data.append('title', 'sda');
        data.append('title_image', testInputs.title_image, testInputs.title_image.name);
        data.append('test_type', 1);
        data.append('question', [1, 2, 4]);
        data.append('result', [1, 2]);
        console.log(data.get('title_image'))
        axios({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/tests/',
            data: data
        })
```

вот что я получаю на сервере

```
<QueryDict: {
    'author': ['1'],
    'title': ['sda'],
    'test_type': ['1'],
    'question': ['1,2,4'],
    'result': ['1,2'],
    'title_image': [<InMemoryUploadedFile:  netherlands.png (image/png)>]}>
```

как мне это сделать ?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137018/discussion-on-question-by-vahe-hakobjanyan------).

Answer (score 0):

Ты добавляешь неправильно:

```js
const data = new FormData();

data.append('question', [1, 2, 4]);
console.log(data.getAll('question'));

for (var x of [1, 2, 4]) data.append('answer', x);
console.log(data.getAll('answer'));
```